# How to pass schema name in a parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement

I need to add the schema value dynamically to the query. I was trying to construct it the way we usually use values but realised it does not work with the schema names the same way.

This was what I was trying to do

```
sql = "SELECT Name FROM [@dbo].[Members]";
...
command.Parameters.Add("@dbo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "dbo";
```

I know I can construct the query by directly adding the variable in the query like this:

```
sql = $@"SELECT Name FROM [{parameter}].[Members]";
```

But I wanted to disallow any kind of SQL Injection so want to go ahead using the parameterized query as above.

Can anyone help with a possible idea to implement this?

TIA

Comment: You can't. The schema is not a *parameter*. Query parameters are  equivalent to function parameters in eg C#. They're used to pass values. In SQL, the table and columns are equivalent to C# types and properties. You can't specify them by name.

Comment: You can't parameterize any names in a query. But if you put the given value in brackets `[{parameter}]` you are already quite save. But to be really sure, you should check if `parameter` contains a closing bracket `]` and if yes, don't use that value ...

Comment: @derpirscher `are already quite safe` not at all. `Members]; drop table users; --`

Comment: @derpirscher I tried doing a Veracode scan after doing the same. It still flags it as unsafe code

Comment: @SurajNair because it is. It's still vulnerable to SQL injection. What are you trying to do in the first place? You simply can't pass tables and schema as parameters because they aren't. If you want to execute a SQLCMD script, eg to create or seed a database, you can use script variables.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's why I added the comment about checking for a closing bracket in `parameter` and rejecting the execution if there is one ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you pls suggest a workaround to get over the SQL Injection in such a case?

Comment: @SurajNair what case? You still haven't explained what you want to do. Changing the schema or table in a query doesn't make much sense. It's the same as changing `Sales.Record` for `Diagnostics.Record` in a C# function. Sure, the name of the class is the same, but they're two completely different classes and most likely, completely unrelated. Your C# code wouldn't even compile

Comment: @SurajNair if you have to, you could query `sys.tables` to see if the schema and table are correct and if they are, construct the query in C# using concatenation *only for the schema and table name*. This will cost an extra query though. This may be acceptable in a rarely used query, or too expensive if the query is used all the time. Again, what are you trying to do? There may be other ways to do it.

Comment: It sounds more to me that depending on the schema name you want to invoke different statically defined queries, not dynamically click one together.

Comment: @Gimby yea thats what I am trying do in my project

Comment: @SurajNair no you're not, you are trying to dynamically click together a query. Your code proves that. What I'm trying to say is that if you need to handle three different schemas, your code should have three queries, one for each schema. And you pick the one that matches the schema.

Comment: @SurajNair So if that's the case why would you need to make the schema name parameterized? Just define your queries for each schema, and select the correct one depending on the value of `parameter`

Answer (score 1):

The schema is not a parameter. Query parameters are equivalent to function parameters in eg C#. They're used to pass values. In SQL, the table and columns are equivalent to C# types and properties. You can't specify them by name. The schema in a SQL query is similar to the Namespace in C#. The table is equivalent to a Type. In C#, just because `Sales.Record` and `Diagnostics.Record` have the same type name doesn't mean the two types can be used the same way.

The question doesn't explain *why* the schema name is passed dynamically. It's almost certain there are easier, more efficient and safer ways to query similar tables in multiple schemas, but the solution would depend on the actual problem.

There are some techniques that can be used to make such a dynamic query safe if not efficient. *I'd really, **really** try to avoid treating the schema as a value though.*

**Using QUOTENAME**

One option, is to use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in a `T-SQL` script to construct a dynamic query. At least this way a syntax error will be thrown if the schema and table names are wrong:

```
sql = @"declare @sql nvarchar(max)='SELECT Name FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbo) + '.[Members]';
select @sql;
exec sp_executesql @sql;";
...
command.Parameters.Add("@dbo", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100).Value = "dbo";
```

`QUOTENAME` will convert something like `sys].schemas; PRINT ''x''; --` to  `[[sys]].schemas; PRINT 'x'; --]`. This will result in an error :

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)= 'select * from [' +quotename('sys].schemas; PRINT ''x''; --')
select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql;
--------
select * from [[sys]].schemas; PRINT 'x'; --]

Invalid object name '[sys].schemas; PRINT 'x'; --'.
```

It's too easy to make quoting mistakes with such scripts. This could be extracted into a stored procedure :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMemberNameBySchema
     @dbo nvarchar(100)
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)='SELECT Name FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbo) + '.[Members]';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Verify the Schema name**

Query `sys.schema` to ensue the schema is correct before constructing the query. Let's say you're using Dapper (so I don't have to write all the ADO.NET code) :

```
var schema="dbo";
var isValid=connection.ExecuteScalar<bool?>(
    "select 1 from sys.schema where name=@name",
    new {name=schema});
//isValid will be null if nothing is found
if(isValid ==true)
{
    var names=connection.Query($"SELECT Name FROM [{schema}].[Members]");
    ...
}
```

This is safe to do because the first query ensured the schema name is valid.

Comment: Okay now I got your point. I don't need to make the exists clause in dynamic query. Good learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass parameters to dynamic query not object names as far as I know. You can do something like below:

Update after seeing Panagiotis' solution. we can take out the exists part outside. I am no expert in C# but something similar we want to do:

```
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(50);

SET @Schema = 'dbo';  --This part will come from C#
SET @Table = 'Tablename';  --This part will come from C#

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @Table and schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@Schema))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = N'SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@Schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) +';';
  PRINT @sql;
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END 
ELSE
  RAISERROR('Table or Schema doesn''t exist.',16,1);
```

In the `IF EXISTS` you need to pass the table name and schema name as parameter to dynamic query.

In the actual query you need to make a concatenation of table name and schema name.

This will prevent sql injection as well and if the table is not there then raise an error.

Comment: That's invalid syntax. And dynamic queries have no parameters. What you typed would only work in a `sqlcmd` script, with `$dbo` and `$Table` defined as variables, not parameters. This *script* won't work through ADO.NET

Comment: This is an illustration not actual code. the complete code need to be dynamic in the C#. for example in sql server. `EXEC sp_executesql @sql,@table = @table, @schema = @schema` where in `@sq`l will have @table and @schema as paramters but $table and $schema as direct concatenation of the values.

Comment: What does this code illustrate? It can't even run. It can't be executed with `sp_executesql`. The parameters are never used in the query itself. Again, this would only run in a SQLCMD script with  `$Schema` and `$Table` variables. The SqlCmd tool will replace these placeholders with the actual values before executing the script. This simply can't be executed as SQL using `sp_executesql` or `SqlCommand`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Added the code that you can check in SQL server

Comment: You gain nothing by doing this in SQL. What would work would be to query `sys.tables` in *C#* and if that succeeds create the query by concatenation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sys.tables can ensure that the table exists in database and using it in IF EXISTS make sure that query should execute only of the given table exists in the given schema else throw an error. This prevents SQL injection as well becuase IF Exists is taking the names as parameter (not concatenated in dynamic string.)

Comment: And once again you gain nothing by doing that in T-SQL except increase the chance of errors due to multiple concatenations and quoting. Again, the answer, as written, still contains invalid code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The one gain you have is the use of `QUOTENAME`, which wasn't actually done here. Even if you query `syst.tables` you still need to escape

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont know how it is not working for you. it works like charm for me. check your SQL settings. I have removed the suggested code with actual implementation.

Comment: @Charlieface indeed. As it is, the query string is **still vulnerable** to SQL injection, just a little bit harder. Passing `dbo].Members; END; drop table users;--` as the @Schema value will still result in SQL injection

Comment: @DeepakPawar the problem is that what you posted doesn't work for anyone. The first snippet was invalid. And this snippet is just as vulnerable to SQL injection. As long as you construct the entire script by concatenation, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. You'd avoid this if the `IF` block was normal SQL and only the final query was constructed using concatenation, ie `declare @sql nvarchar(max) ='SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ['+@Schema+'].['+@Table+'];`. Even better, use `QUOTENAME` as an extra precaution `declare @sql nvarchar(max) ='SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '+QUOTENAME(@Schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@Table);`

Comment: And an even better one - don't do the check in the dynamic query. There's no reason to. `QUOTENAME` will cause bad data to throw a syntax error. The *entire* dynamic query will fail. The schema and table names will never be checked. If you're OK with a syntax error, you don't need to check the names at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as I said in my suggestion which I removed as it was causing issue in explaination. The dynamic query should be formed in C# and parameter as well. You wanted to see how it will work then I implemented my suggestion in SQL server. The thing I did in SQL server need to be done in C# but not exactly the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you seems to be right. the code will still give error if not properly used with correct paramters. The concatenation can be exploited. I keep the answer posted so that anyone can refer it if they come to similar situation.